# How to tune the parameters for a better insert performance in Postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, performance

The dataset is consist of two folders, each of them has 180 CSV files. My python script will read two CSV files from those two folders each time for 180 loops.

After reading the data and some data processing, the data from two CSV files is merged to one list, with the shape`[(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), ...]`. There would be about `3,000,000,000` tuples in the list.

I first revised some parameters (as below) of `postgresql.conf`, and tried to insert the whole list to DB at once by `executemany`, it took like `30,000` seconds, which would take me two months to read them out.
Then I tried to split the list to 30 sub-lists and read them one after another. Reading sub-list each took about `230` seconds, which is much faster, but will still coast 15 days.

I will probably use multiprocessing since I have more RAM and CPUs to use (one process uses 35 GB memory, I guess I will try to use three processes). But I would like to ask, can I somehow optimize the parameters of DB for a better insert performance in this step? Because the psql documentation did not talk much about the parameter tuning, except to set the `share_buffers` to 25% of RAM would enhance the performance.

Thanks in advance!

My current parameters, that are not followed by default:

```
shared_buffers = 10 GB
temp_buffers = 1GB
max_wal_size = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 20GB
work_mem = 2GB
maintenance_work_mem = 4GB
```

ENV: Redhat, RAM: 150 GB, NUmber of kerns: 40

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking this? https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from

Comment: @MikeOrganek No, I haven't. Because I have to read the files and do some data processing. Will it be faster if I write the data to CSV after processing, then read the data from CSV and insert to the DB?

Comment: When you do the data processing, write the results to a string and then use `StringIO` to treat the string as a file when you do `copy_from()`.

Comment: From the docs (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany):  "Warning In its current implementation this method is not faster than executing execute() in a loop. For better performance you can use the functions described in Fast execution helpers."